# Multiple Conditional Events

Tags: conditional-statements, simpy

I have a collection of resources. An incoming process would require a set of resources. For example, let's say I have resources A, B, C, and D in the collection and a process comes along asking for resource A, B and D; I would like the process to stop until A, B and D become available.

This of course is a trivial example. I would like to know if one can generate a list of Resource.request() events and then use yield and '&' or some other method to wait until all of them are granted (i.e. all events are triggered).

Here's what I'm doing....

```
req1 = A.request()
req2 = B.request()
req3 = D.request()
yield req1 & req2 & req3
```

Here's what I would like to do....

```
list_of_resources_needed = [A,B,D]
req_list = []
for r in list_of_resources_needed:
    req_list.append(r.request())
yield * All events in req_list *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AllOf` or `AnyOf` events, for which the `Environment` provides shortcuts: http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.core.html#simpy.core.Environment.all_of